# without modrewrite, but with index.php, still broken things

Tags: cakephp

I read about using xdebug with cakephp. I renamed three .htaccess files, one in `/`, one in `/app`, one in `/app/webroot`, then uncommented `Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));` in app/config/core.php, then typed index.php before controller name, but css broke and a captcha fonts folder broke too. Inserting /app/webroot after /projects/iloved in the default layout's css url fixes css, but it may be breaking other things, because the captcha fonts folder is still broken. If I have to change from using modwrite to using index.php, what should I do to have urls that work?

Comment: So, you can't get to your css from eg: /app/webroot/css/css.php ?  Or you can't access it some other way because you deleted your .htaccess file?

Comment: I think the url in the source code (<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/projects/iloved/css/cake.generic.css" />) is pointing to no css, because I renamed three htaccess files. Is that what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 2):

Use Cakephp's html helper to build your CSS links. If you are not using mod rewrite, your css links should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/projects/iloved/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css" />
```